# Get Data from Tableview to Viewcontroller containing Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I try to pass data between two tableviews ,for example once the person tap on a row in the first tableview you will see more data in the 2nd tableview .Actually the application runs but there is no data in the second tableview .

Comment: Have you checked that `arrayOfNewspaper` isn't empty or nil and that it actually contains `UIImage` objects?

Comment: And it contains `UIImages`?  Have you set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  Is it called? Have you set the delegate and table source for your second table?

Comment: Check that `cell.imagecell` isn't nil.

Comment: You could try adding a call to `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewDidLoad` but you shouldn't need anything in that method.  Did you check that `cell.imagecell` isn't nil - ie. Did you connect the image view in the prototype cell in storyboard to the IBOutlet in your custom class?

Answer (score 0):

Does your header label appear? Then the problem can be narrowed down to PFFile object stuffs.

First of all, you should make sure that any images you want to display are downloaded and stored in the memory from Parse server. When it comes to Parse object, PFFile (image) is just a reference to the actual file in the Parse server. Therefore, you should download the actual image before you use it locally like setting it in an image view.

To get a single image PFFile from the server:

```
PFFile *file = dictionary[@"thumbnail"];
[file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *thumbnailData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {  // downloaded successfully 
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnailData];
      ....
    }
 }
```

In your case, it seems that multiple images are stored in the `newspaper` array, so all of them must be downloaded first if you want to access one of them. Reload the second table view data then.

Prepare 'dictionaryOfNewspaperImage' and override viewDidAppear method in your second vc like below:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayofnewspaper count]; i++) {        
        PFFile *file = self.arrayofnewspaper[i];
        [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1];
                [self.dictionaryOfNewspaperImage setObject:image forKey:indexPath];
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your cell configuration part should seem like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
    cell.imageView.image = self.dictionaryOfNewspaperImage[indexPath];
    ....
    return cell;
}
```

Not quite sure if it's reliable to use NSIndexPath as a key and there should be better approach than this, but you'll get the idea. Get the file from Parse first and reload relevant rows later.

Comment: what about the the array

Comment: Just enumerate the array to download an image and add it to a local array. After all done without one single error, access the local array to get a particular image. It seems quite inefficient, but this is the way for your situation.

Comment: I'd recommend you to change some design regarding Parse. You have designed a process that needs to get all the images from server only to use just one of them. Change your code so that the only PFFile image you want to display can be downloaded once a user selects a row.

Comment: As a private property in your second vc. Please note that all of the cells must be populated first as soon as view appears. Only images will be populated as soon as they are fetched from the server.

Comment: No, I can't. The code you posted is very limited and especially it's not feasible to mimic the Parse environment of yours. By the way, have you tried the suggestions that I made? I mean, have you ever successfully fetched a single image from Parse server? Please try and test if you can retrieve one image and assign it to a local UIImage.

Comment: What do you mean by "queried a lot"? Have you ever get the actual images from Parse?

Comment: Download images from parse do you know any other way I could change my code

Comment: Using a dictionary like I suggested is not an important issue. I would like to know if you can fetch an image PFFile from Parse and put it into whatever the kind of storage is (array, dictionary, or even a single UIImage object).

Comment: But your original code doesn't include that actual fetching process (the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` stuff) anywhere. Is that something that you have learned after you posted this question?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. This is gonna be my last comment on the problem as I don't want to use this as a chat interface. 1. Do the PFFile fetching for one PFFile. 2. If you can (Double check that you can actually display the fetched image on screen!!), scale that skills to get multiple images referenced by your array. 3. Store them in any kind of collections and make your table view data source methods access it to populate your second vc' table.

Comment: i need your help ,i query the images , save it to PFFile ,but i am stocked here because i can't assign the PFFile to the array @iamjkim

Comment: Provide me with more information. What you have  done, your code, whatever.

Comment: I edited my code now the secondviewcontroller is UIViewcontroller containing a tableview the delegate was set@iamjkim

Comment: Did you query images and download them successfully? Then why did you reference the images via PFFile type pointer? They are NSData in the first place, and UIImage if you've done the conversion.

Comment: I check the query they were download successful ,i was trying to use PFFile because PFImageView had this property (.file) i was thinking to assign the file to the PFImageView in the secondView

Comment: i have to UIImage saved and also i NSLOG it ,it has the data inside of it .now in the second view i was trying to save the image and the array but its not working @imakjim

Comment: please bro can you help with the second part@iamjkim

Answer (score 0):

When you change the data source for the second table, you need to notify the table of the change by calling its reloadData method.

In this case it might be

```
destviewcontroller.arrayofnewspaper=[object objectForKey:@"newspaper"];
[destviewcontroller.table reloadData];
```

Comment: What do you mean change my Data source , please

Comment: The arrayofnewspaper property is the data source for filling out cells.  When it is changed, the second table needs to be notified.  You do that by calling [destviewcontroller.table reloadData].  (Assuming the second table is held in destviewcontroller.table. If not, then use the appropriate property.)